# assert property: Pass value from property block to assert block

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I have property on the form

```
property p1;
  logic [31:0] data;
  @(posedge clk) (trigger, data = data) |=> !resolve[*0:$] ##1 resolve && checkPassed;
endproperty
```

Which is used in an assertion

```
assert property(p1) else begin
  $error("Assertion failed. data = %h", ?);
end
```

Whenever the assertion fails, I want to print the stored data of the specific property instance used for that assertion. Is there any way to reference the internal variables of the property or in any way pass the data from the property block to the assert block?

Comment: can you use non-local data instead?

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful to the person answering a question for the questioner to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Here is an MCVE:

```
module testing;

  bit a, b, clk;

  always #5 clk = ~clk;

  initial begin
    #20 a = 1'b1;
    #20;
    $finish;
  end

  property p1;
    logic [31:0] data;
    @(posedge clk) (a, data = 3) |=> b;
  endproperty

  assert property(p1) else begin
    // $error("Assertion failed. data = %h", ??? );
  end

endmodule
```

And here is a solution:

```
module testing;

  bit a, b, clk;

  always #5 clk = ~clk;

  logic [31:0] d;

  initial begin
    #20 a = 1'b1;
    #20;
    $finish;
  end

  task store (input logic [31:0] data);
    d = data;
  endtask

  property p1;
    logic [31:0] data;
    @(posedge clk) (a, data = 3, store(data)) |=> b;
  endproperty

  assert property(p1) else begin
    $error("Assertion failed. data = %h", d);
  end

endmodule
```

You can do one of three things after the comma in the `( , )` construct:

1) Initialise a local variable

2) Increment or decrement a local variable

3) Call a task or function.

I used a task to copy the local variable to a variable with module scope. This can then be accessed by the `$error` system task in the action block.

Technically, I think copying the local variable to a variable with module scope in the task is illegal; I think the task called in an assertion should have no side effects. However, Aldec Riviera Pro was happy with it.